# How to create vertical menu styling treeview control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and am struggling to put the pieces of information together. I am trying to create a two level vertical menu like the one [here](http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.7.1/). I have achieved my desired look by overriding the control template of tree view items.

Here is my code.

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />

<Style x:Key="MenuText" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFA7B1C2"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

</Style>

<Style x:Key="MenuIcon" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseIconTextBlockStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFA7B1C2"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

</Style>

<Style x:Key="MenuToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="46"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        </Trigger>


    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemNormal" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToggleButton Grid.Row="0" Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Style="{StaticResource MenuToggleButton}" >
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" >

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="25,0" >
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Icon" Style="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MenuText" Style="{StaticResource MenuText}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>



                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF293846"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MenuText">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF19AA8D"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>

        <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemParent" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToggleButton x:Name="MenuButton" Grid.Row="0" Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Style="{StaticResource MenuToggleButton}" >
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="25,0" >
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Icon" Style="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MenuText" Style="{StaticResource MenuText}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Chevron" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource MenuIcon}"  Text="&#xf104;" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF293846"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MenuText">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chevron">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF19AA8D"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chevron">
                                            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="&#xf107;"/>
                                        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>

            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ChildContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:00:.500"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ChildContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:00:.500"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToggleButton.Triggers>

        </ToggleButton>

        <StackPanel x:Name="ChildContainer"  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MenuButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0"></ScaleTransform>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemChild" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToggleButton Grid.Row="0" Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Style="{StaticResource MenuToggleButton}" >
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#FF293846">

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="25,0" >
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Icon" Style="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" Text="&#xf192;"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MenuText" Style="{StaticResource MenuText}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>



                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF293846"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MenuText">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF19AA8D"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>

        <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And in my Window I declare Treeview like this.

```
 <TreeView x:Name="Menu" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <TreeViewItem Tag="&#xf009;" Header="Dashboard" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemNormal}"  />

            <TreeViewItem Tag="&#xf015;" Header="Home" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemNormal}"  />

            <TreeViewItem Tag="&#xf1fe;" Header="Reporting" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemNormal}" />

            <TreeViewItem Tag="&#xf07a;" Header="Sell" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemNormal}" />

            <TreeViewItem Tag="&#xf03a;" Header="Products" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemParent}"  >
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2.1" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemChild}"  />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2.2" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemChild}" />
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Tag="&#xf1da;" Header="Sales Ledger" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemNormal}" />

            <TreeViewItem Tag="&#xf0c0;" Header="Customers" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemNormal}" />

            <TreeViewItem Tag="&#xf0ad;" Header="Setup" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemNormal}" />
        </TreeView>
```

The problem is that now I realize I should have probably overridden the data 
template of the tree view item because I want to bind the tree view to a property on my view model. I cannot figure out if I use data template how do I remove the default ugly expander icon that comes with tree view items

Specifically I have 3 questions

1. Is overriding control template the right way to achieve what I am
   trying to do?
2. How do I bind my tree view to a view model property
   instead of hard coding the items?
3. How do I track the selected item in my view model?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit concerned by the fact that you want to create a menu without using `Menu` and customizing the visual appearance. WPF tends to support re-styling the correct functional control with a new look instead of tweaking the right-looking control with new functionality. However, its not completely clear whether you actually want a menu or really a single-item-select-tree.

Comment: Generally speaking *"Specifically I have 3 questions"* is an indicator for too broad questions. If you really have three questions, consider asking three questions, so answers can be focused on a single question.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this type of menu http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.7.1/ and in my opinion it's behavior is more like a tree view rather than menu that's why I opted for tree view. If I had chosen menu control, I would have to re-template it as well probably ending up in a similar situation.

Comment: Asking 3 questions in 1 does not mean these are 3 different questions, I think everything is related to creating this menu. I have written 3 questions because people sometimes ask what is it exactly that you want us to answer? and asking them to tell me how to build this menu would have been too broader question in my opinion.

Comment: Well *surprise*, https://stackoverflow.com/a/725933/5265292 covers only one of your three questions, so lets answer the other two: (2) use `ItemsSource` and `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (3) use `IsSelected` or `Command`